# What are the current options of Pushing notifications to iOS?

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, push-notification, signalr, push

I need to Push JSON objects on a high volume from a .NET WEB API server to iOS native app. 
What is my best option? I have used SignalR before, but as far I understand there is no native iOS SDK.

Comment: Are you asking what service you should use?

Comment: No, no SaaS. I need a library like SignalR.

Comment: So, you've tagged this post under iOS and asp.net-mvc.  Which one do you need this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native iOS SDK is Xcode (Objective-C).
Native iOS code can also be generated via PhoneGap (Cordova -HTML,CSS, Javascript), Titanium (HTML,CSS, Javascript), or Xamarin (C#).

Without Push Providers:
Using the same principles as shown in the tutorial below, you can push high volume from your server to the Apple Push Notification Servers.
Here is a tutorial on how to send push notifications on iOS, without using a 3rd party push service:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3YlqWWnI6s&list=UUKT8c1fBqp8l30wWF32-t5g

Alternatively
Push Providers:
For options on using a Push Service Provider for push have a look at: Urban Airship, Parse, Azure Services, PushBots .
Each has loads of info on setting up an using iOS push notifications.

Automating your pushes:
If you want to automate regular pushes from a server, consider setting up a CRON job to run a server side script which sends your JSON package to a push service provider (see above).

Hope this gets you what you're looking for.